# For two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ which one of the following is correct?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f.g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions . We can conclude that

$h(x) \le f(x)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, if we define $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as:

(a) $\text{min}(g(x) , f(x) + g(x))$

(b) $\text{min}(f(x) , f(x) + g(x))$

(c) $\text{max}(g(x) , f(x) + g(x))$

(d) $\text{max}(f(x) , f(x) + g(x))$

If I take $f=  -6$ and $g = 10$ then clearly option (b) seems to be only correct .
However I am trying to prove this statement  more rigorously.

Can anyone tell me how should I proceed to prove this more rigorously ?

Comment: Well, that's enough to prove $a,c,d$ are wrong answers.  But now you have to show that $b$ is a right answer always.

Answer (score 1):

To disprove a, c, and d, a single counterexample suffices, such as the one you have given.

To prove b, you must prove it for any $f$ and $g$.
This is not too hard, since by the definition of minimum,
$$\min(f(x), f(x) + g(x)) \le f(x), \; \forall x.$$
(The minimum of two quantities is smaller than either of the two quantities.)

Answer (score 0):

$f=1$ and $g=2$ is a counterexample for a), c) and d). To prove that something is false it is enough to give one counterexample. In this example the functions are independent of $x$. In the case of ), for example it suffices to observe that $\min (2,1+2) >1$. Similarly for c) and d). This is completely rigorous.

Proof of b) is immediate from the fact that minimum of two numbers is always less then or equal to either of them.

Comment: S/he already had a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Note:  $\min (a, M) \le a$ *always*.  And $\max (a, M) \ge a$. *always*.

Keeping that in mind these become simple:

a) $h(x)= \min(g(x), f(x)+g(x))$

We just need functions where there exists an $x_0$ where $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$ and $f(x_0) < f(x_0) + g(x_0)$.  Then second occurs if $g(x_0)> 0$ and the first occurs if ... $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$.  We can certainly find functions and values where that happen.  You constant function $f(x)=-6$ and $g(x) =10$ will do.

But we just need one $x$ where that is true if $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$ we can have $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$.

It's certainly *not* true that $\min(\cos x, \sin x + \cos x) \le \sin x$ *always*.

b)  $h(x) =\min(f(x), f(x)+g(x)) \le f(x)$ always.  Because for any $x_0\in \mathbb R$ we have $h(x_0) = \min(f(x_0), f(x_0)  + g(x_0)) \le f(x_0)$.

c)  we just need to find have a point $x_0$ where $f(x_0) < \max(g(x_0), f(x_0) + g(x_0))$.  We can surely do that.  If $g_(x_0) > 0$ then $f(x_0) < f(x_0) + g(x_0) \le  \max(g(x_0), f(x_0) + g(x_0))$

And even if $g_(x) < 0$ for all $x$ we'd just need a point $x_0$ where $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$ which is obviously possible. Then $f(x_0) < g(x_0) \le \max(g(x_0), f(x_0) + g(x_0))$

Again we can you $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x) = \cos x$ as it certainly is *not* true that $\max(\cos x, \cos x + \sin x) \le \sin x$ always.  $\sin 0$ is a counterpoint as is $\sin(240) = -\frac {\sqrt 3}2 < -\frac 12 = \cos (240) = \max(\cos 240, \cos 240 + \sin 240)$.

d)  $f(x) \le \max(f(x) ,f(x) + g(x))=h(x)$ so we just need one point where $f(x_0) \ne \max(f(x_0), f(x_0) + g(x_0))$.  That will happen if ever $f(x_0) + g(x_0) > f(x_0)$ which happens if $g(x_0) > 0$.  Which can obviously occur.